# How to get protected attribute of class in another class

Tags: abap, sap-fiori

I need to get protected attribute `attr_1` of class `Class_1` in my own `Z-class` and use it as an input parameter for my method `GET_CAMP_DATA()`.

Can anybody help me to solve my problem?

I want to do something like this:

```
DATA(lv_camp_id) = Class_1=>attr_1`.

CALL METHOD GET_CAMP_DATA
EXPORTING
  iv_camp_id            = lv_camp_id
IMPORTING
  et_result             = lt_result
```

Comment: One option is to define the attribute PUBLIC (you can use the addition READ-ONLY so it cannot be changed from outside). If that is not feasible, than you have to create a GET method for the attribute.

Comment: By definition (search the web), "protected" means that it can only be used by the class itself or one of its sub-classes (a class defined as inheriting the members from the class). If the class owner don't want other developers to access it, they won't be able to access it. In ABAP, you have the possibility to use the Enhancement Framework, but that's another question...

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sandra. That's what I expected ...

Answer (score 1):

Three options:

1.Implement a method `get_attr_1` in Class_1, return `attr_1` in this method.

2.Set `attr_1` as `public` and [read-only](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapdata_options.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_2@2@)

```
class Class_1 definition
  public
  final
  create public global friends Z-class.

   public section.
    data attr_1 type your_type read-only.

   protected section.

   private section.

endclass.
```

3.Define `Z-class` as a [friend](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenfriends.htm) of `Class_1`

```
class Class_1 definition
  public
  final
  create public global friends Z-class.

   public section.

   protected section.
    data: attr_1 type your_type.

   private section.

endclass.
```